# Best way to separate a list into two new list based on a condition

Tags: javascript

I am looking for nice good method to split array to two new arrays based on a condition.
Lets assume we have a list containing same structure objects, the object has a bool property, lets call it condition and we want two new list where we have only the same condition elements.

```
const cont1 = myArray.filter((el) => el.condition)
const cont2 = myArray.filter((el) => !el.condition)
```

This could work I guess but I am wondering if there is better single iteration verzion of this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option would be to use `reduce`, which will functionally separate all the items in only a single iteration over the array:

```js
const myArray = [
  { condition: true },
  { condition: true },
  { condition: false },
]
const [cont1, cont2] = myArray.reduce(([cont1, cont2], item) => {
  (item.condition ? cont1 : cont2).push(item);
  return [cont1, cont2];
}, [[], []]);

console.log('cont1: ', cont1);
console.log('cont2: ', cont2);
```

Or, less functionally but perhaps more readably, you can `.push` to outer variables:

```js
const myArray = [
  { condition: true },
  { condition: true },
  { condition: false },
];
const cont1 = [];
const cont2 = [];
myArray.forEach((item) => {
  (item.condition ? cont1 : cont2).push(item);
});

console.log('cont1: ', cont1);
console.log('cont2: ', cont2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Reduce could work, but reducing onto an object, with 2 different arrays as object members:

```
const arr = [1,2,3];

arr.reduce((acc, next) => {
    if (next % 2 === 1){
        acc.odd.push(next);
    } else {
        acc.even.push(next);
    }
    return acc;
}, { odd: [], even: [] }); // { even: [2], odd: [1,3] }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in a single line like this:

```
myArray.forEach(el=>el.condition?cont1.push(el):cont2.push(el));
```